# Multilevel Categories & Menu - How To?

Tags: nodes

I would like to be able to create content of a particular type but be able to set multi-level categorisation. But I would like a menu where I can select a category and see all content including child categories as well.

e.g.

1. Fruit

   - Local

     - Apples
     - Pears
   - Tropical

     - Pineapple
     - Bananas

'Fruit' menu would show all fruit

'Local' Menu would show all local, apples and pears

'Apple' Menu would only show Apples

I am trying to achieve some thing like this side menu:
http://learningexchange.ptc.com/tutorials/by_product/ptc-creo/product_id:1

Answer (score 1):

There won't be a definite answer to this question as this can be achieved in a lot of possible ways. Depending on your knowledge in drupal you could start with the built-in drupal taxonomy system that enables you to classify your content as needed (e.g. with a tree-like-hierarchy or even related terms). To build the menu you can try the [taxonomy menu module](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) or use Views to create this manually.

For a start i recommend reading through this overview: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy

Comment: I was thinking about using Taxonomy to create the categories and sub-categories. In the content type, allow the use of the term and then create a menu based upon taxonomy terms?

Comment: Essentially I am looking to replicate this menu: http://learningexchange.ptc.com/tutorials/by_product/ptc-creo/product_id:1